# Entity Framework, Code First. How override generation up/down script

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I use bounded contexts (BC) with EF Code-first in my solution to generate database.

Some tables are partially (not with all fields) defined as classes in distinct BC's to add a foreign key for dependent tables, but there is always a BC with a class that defines table with all fields by single class.

I didn't find a way to generate a single migration based on multiple contexts, so I had to add multiple migrations. But in each migration EF adds all the changes in all classes in BC, including partially defined tables. The biggest problems are:

- when I add a partial table, EF wants to add a new table to DB, which
  already exists
- when I need to remove a field only in one class to which table is
  mapped only partially, it wants to remove a field from a table in
  database, which ruins other classes.

The project that I'm working has a dozen odd developers, more than 350 tables, and more than 20 BC's, so changing scripts that are generated by EF Migration by hands sounds like madness.

It seems like the only way to solve it - is to alter the migration pipeline to exclude the creation or alternation of tables defined by classes that marked with specific attribute.

So, is there any other way to solve my problem, or should I hack in the EF source code and inject the bypass routine there?

Comment: See the end of this article where Lerman talks about an "uber-model" of all the tables used for migrations. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/JJ883952.aspx and this more recent article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/Dn948104.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd create one DbContext that has all the tables in it and all relationships, etc. Use that for migrations, keep the bonded contexts that you have for your domain model.